# Can't Remove Link and Command Name from Drop-Down

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, custom-form

I'm just getting into Content Types.  I wanted to create a NewForm for one of my Content Types, so I created a new NewForm (as I've done before) and noticed the "Advanced form options" at the bottom of the "Create New List Form" dialog:

[image: Create New List Form dialog]

This value didn't show up on the ribbon in my list as I expected, in fact I couldn't figure out where it went...until now:

[image: SharePoint Item List Drop-Down]

I guess I did it twice because I couldn't figure out where the values I was typing came through. I deleted those "test" forms, but they still exist in the drop-down.  Any idea how I get rid of them?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out--in SharePoint Designer for the List there's a section called Custom Actions:

[image: SharePoint List Custom Actions Section]

Thanks anyway :)